# Django template for loop without duplicate buttons

Tags: django, templates, for-loop, logic

When I vote for more than one entry, the "Add Vote" button is duplicated for each entry in the for loop. Any ideas as to how I should fix the logic so the add vote button only appears once?

```
                    {{ user.get_profile.votes.all }}

                {% for v in user.get_profile.votes.all %}
                    {% if v.entry = e.entry %}
                        <form action="/profile/" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type='hidden' name='entry_id' value='{{ e.id }}'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='project_id' value='{{ p.id }}'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='team_id' value='{{ t.id }}'>
                        <input type='submit' name="remove_vote" value='Remove Vote'>
                        </form>
                    {% elif v.entry != e.entry %}
                        <form action="/profile/" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type='hidden' name='entry_id' value='{{ e.id }}'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='project_id' value='{{ p.id }}'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='team_id' value='{{ t.id }}'>
                        <input type='submit' name="add_vote" value='Add Vote'>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% empty %}
                        <form action="/profile/" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type='hidden' name='entry_id' value='{{ e.id }}'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='project_id' value='{{ p.id }}'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='team_id' value='{{ t.id }}'>
                        <input type='submit' name="add_vote" value='Add Vote'>
                        </form>
                {% endfor %}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `{% if v.entry = e.entry %}` is not a valid condition check... You are using `assignment operator` (`=`), not `equality check operator` (`==`).

Comment: Thank @fallenangel! I adjusted to burhan's answer, which solves the (==) problem but am still encountering the same issue... any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

In Django you have a forloop counter, you could use it like this:

```
{% if forloop.first %}
    <input type='submit' name="add_vote" value='Add Vote'>
{% endif %}
```

And your button will only in the first round of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @schacki. Where would you place that within burhan's answer? I tried it and am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up your code a bit:

```
          <form action="/profile/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='hidden' name='entry_id' value='{{ e.id }}'>
            <input type='hidden' name='project_id' value='{{ p.id }}'>
            <input type='hidden' name='team_id' value='{{ t.id }}'>

            {% for v in user.get_profile.votes.all %}
                {% ifequal v.entry e.entry %}
                    <input type='submit' name="remove_vote" value='Remove Vote'>
                {% elif v.entry != e.entry %}
                    <input type='submit' name="add_vote" value='Add Vote'>
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
          </form>
```

Since the else action is the same in both cases; you only need to check once for the entry. I also fixed your template as you had one `=` where you need two for comparison.

Comment: Thanks @burhan. Though I'm still seeing an "add vote" button for each entry--why do you think that is?

Comment: You are seeing both buttons or only one button?

Comment: If I click "add vote" for more than one entry, I see "remove vote" on each entry but the one that received the first vote. I used a forloop.first from @schaki's suggestion. `        {% ifequal v.entry e.entry %}
         <input type='submit' name="remove_vote" value='Remove Vote'>
        {% else %}
        {% if forloop.first %}        
         <input type='submit' name="add_vote" value='Add Vote'>
        {% endif %}
        {% endifequal %}`

Comment: Remove the `{% if forloop.first %}`

Comment: If I do that, there is a button created for each entry, for each vote. For example, if there are three entries and I vote on all of them in order, after voting on all of them, the first entry will have three buttons, "Remove Vote", "Add Vote", "Add Vote", the second entry will have "Add Vote", "Remove Vote", "Add Vote" and the third entry will have "Add Vote", "Add Vote", "Remove Vote". Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you can use elif with ifequal. So I changed the elif to if and am having the same problem... `       {% for v in user.get_profile.votes.all %}
       {% ifequal v.entry e.entry %}
       <input type='submit' name="remove_vote" value='Remove Vote'>
       {% endifequal %}
       {% if v.entry != e.entry %}
       <input type='submit' name="add_vote" value='Add Vote'>
       {% endif %}
       {% empty %}
       <input type='submit' name="add_vote" value='Add Vote'>
       {% endfor %}`